# CSS transition works one way (when open nav) but doesn't work when I close

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, css-transitions

This applies to mobile navigation.
Basically when I click to the burger mobile nav slides from the left side.
When I click to the X it doesn't slide but just disappears. Below you will find the CSS.

```
.navigation__list {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
position: absolute;
left: -100%;
bottom: 0;
top: 0;
transition: left .5s,width .5s;
z-index: 60;
background-color: var(--color-main-3);
overflow-y: auto;
width: 0;
border-top-right-radius: 30px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
padding: 0 16px;
```

When I click to the burger it applies the class `.mobile-nav-open` to the `<body>`

```
.mobile-nav-open .navigation__list {
left: 0;
width: calc(100% - 40px);
max-width: 728px;
```

When I click to the X the class `.mobile-nav-open` removes from the `<body>` and navigation just disappears rather slides back.

In fact transition always there (when it closed and opened), but animation works just one way.

I did the same way on other projects and it worked fine, but now for some reason it doesn't work.